# How to detect when virtual navigation bar is opened or closed in React Native

Tags: react-native

How to detect if user close the virtual navigation bar in react native on android at the bottom, I want to call a function when user closed the navigation bar.

and if you can answer to detect navigation bar is open too it will be appreciated, thanks.

I'm on the react native latest version 0.57